# Privoxy whitelist faulty on redirect

Tags: raspberry-pi, whitelist, debian-jessie, privoxy

My problem, in a nutshell, is the following:

I use Privoxy to set up a whitelist of sites in Raspbian Jessie on Chromium. I have Chromium start on boot with the following snippet in lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart:

```
@privoxy
@chromium --incognito --kiosk --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8118
```

This does work as intended, with every site except the ones I specify blacklisted.

Now I edited /privoxy/templates/blocked so that instead of the usual site it will give me a redirect to a certain site should a link be opened that is not on the whitelist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
(Stuff happens)
Please go back to <a href="www.example.com" target="_self">this site.</a>
```

example.com being one of the sites I whitelisted. The problem is, it simply redirects me to the "blocked" page again, making me stuck in a loop. Does anyone have a clue why this would be and how I could work around it? I tried using

```
window.history.back()
```

however it doesn't seem to work either.

I use Kiosk mode because I want to use this in a context where entereing URL-adresses is not desired, just to clarify my Chromium-call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it, at least partially. Turns out that I need to add http:// in front of the URL, since it gets added to the already existing URL otherwise. Which is fair, but a bit awkward for me to admit. HTML isn't exactly my forté. Marking it as solved and keeping it, just in case somebody stumbles upon a similar problem.